How can I prevent lazy collections from excessively re-evaluating conditional child views?
Given a LazyHStack inside a ScrollView, child views are generally re-evaluated only as they come on screen, or if their underlying state changes. However, if the child views contain a conditional statement, this behavior breaks down. When the underlying state changes, all views that have been displayed so far are re-evaluated, even those that are well off screen. Why exactly does this happen, and are there any good workarounds to prevent this?
I have included some basic example code below, to be run in a Playground. To see the issue I'm talking about, do the following:

Uncomment the lines below "This will cause unnecessary re-evaluation" and run the code
Scroll a good way through the collection, then press the "Mutate collection" button. Note that "Evaluating (n)" will be printed for every single child item that has been displayed, even those that aren't visible
Comment out the code from step (1), and uncomment the simple Text view under "This is fine". Run the code again.
Repeat step (2), noting that "Evaluating (n)" is only printed for the child items in the immediate vicinity of those displayed on screen (the desired behavior)

struct ChildView: View {
    let s: String
    var body: some View {

        // This will cause unnecessary re-evaluation
        // if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        //     Text(s)
        //         .draggable("test")
        // } else {
        //     Text(s)
        // }

        // This is fine
        // Text(s)
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var items = Array(0...100)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { n in
                    let _ = print("Evaluating \(n)")
                    ChildView(s: "Num \(n)")
                }
            }
        }
        Button("Mutate collection") {
            items[0] = Int.random(in: 0...100)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 500)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ParentView())



this is normal, it isn't rendering anything, it's just making simple structs which is negligible performance-wise. SwiftUI diffs the structs from last time and then uses the difference inits/updates/deinits all the UIKit objects which actually do the rendering. You can improve diff performance by making your structs as small as possible and only declare the lets actually needed in body.

It's still strange that a seemingly innocuous change results in this different behavior. Even if the performance hit is negligible in most cases, it's preferable to keep the original behavior for very large collections.

I bet id: \.self is the issue, you need to use a real ID property for change tracking to work correctly

No, I'm aware of the pitfalls of using id: \.self. This was just a bare-bones example. The same behavior can be recreated using ForEach on an array of Identifiable items.

So the problem is explained here “try to flatten nested ForEach” https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10160?time=1087

I don't know why it happens, but the solution that I found was encapsulating the mutating view in a view that which it won't affect it:
struct ChildView: View {
    let s: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if #available(iOS 16, *) {
                Text(s)
                    .draggable("test")
            } else {
                Text(s)
            }
        }
    }
}


Group is useful for this

Main use of group is to apply a modifier to an if

@malhal Did you try using a Group in this instance? Strangely enough, the original ZStack suggestion prevents re-evaluation as desired, but using Group does not.

Make the number of views per row constant, explained here
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10160?time=1087

The basic equation to think about is that the row count resulting from
a ForEach in a List is equal to the number of elements multiplied by
the number of views produced for each element. You need to ensure the
number of views per element is a constant, or SwiftUI has to build the
views in addition to the identifiers in order to identify the rows.

So I suppose the runtime if makes it think it’s not constant.

Thanks! This doesn't fully explain why a conditional returning the same number or even type of view in each branch results in this behavior, but I think this is definitely on the right track.

I guess the conditional is enough for it to decide it isn't going to be the same number, even though in your case it is
